# dd running past end of input device

Tags: linux, dd

I'm trying to use `dd` to clone a hard drive I repaired. I'm trying to make `dd` copy data off of the drive in 10GB chunks, however it is transferring more data than the drive should contain. The drive itself functions, and the partition on it can be mounted.

Using `df -h` I got the drive's size to be 1000204886016 bytes (1TB drive).

I initially tried:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sdb of=/dev/sdd status=progress
```

However that slowed down to a crawl after about 300GB, and eventually failed due to a read error. I decided to try copying it in 10GB chunks. I calculated that reading 10GB with a 128kByte block size requires copying 78125 blocks.

To do this I am using:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sdb of=/dev/sdd bs=128k count=78125 status=progress oflag=seek_bytes seek=n
```

`dd` was reporting that 10240000000 bytes were transferred each time. To calculate the seek value for each iteration I aggregated the transferred bytes, and subtracted 1GB to ensure there was some overlap. The resulting sequence is:

```
seek=0
seek=9240000000
seek=18480000000
seek=27720000000
seek=36960000000
...
seek=1071840000000
```

I wrote those up in a shell script with discrete dd commands and ran it. I left the last iteration free to copy as much data as was needed.

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sdb of=/dev/sdd bs=128k count=78125 status=progress oflag=seek_bytes seek=0
sudo dd if=/dev/sdb of=/dev/sdd bs=128k count=78125 status=progress oflag=seek_bytes seek=9240000000
sudo dd if=/dev/sdb of=/dev/sdd bs=128k count=78125 status=progress oflag=seek_bytes seek=18480000000
sudo dd if=/dev/sdb of=/dev/sdd bs=128k count=78125 status=progress oflag=seek_bytes seek=27720000000
sudo dd if=/dev/sdb of=/dev/sdd bs=128k count=78125 status=progress oflag=seek_bytes seek=36960000000
    ...
sudo dd if=/dev/sdb of=/dev/sdd bs=128k status=progress oflag=seek_bytes seek=1071840000000
```

It should have run far past the end of the drive by that last iteration, however it just kept on going. The clone mounts, but is clearly corrupted and missing data.

1. Is there something wrong with my math, or the arguments I used with `dd`?
2. Is there a better way for me to write a 'dd' command to get the data out in 10GB chunks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I discovered the reason my solution failed was misunderstanding what the seek flag did. It was only shifting the write location on the output drive. So the script was just copying the first 10GB over and over again onto the output. It would never reach the end of the device.

To shift the input the skip flag needed to be used as well:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sdb of=/dev/sdd bs=128k count=78125 status=progress skip=n seek=n
```

Setting `oflag=seek_bytes` and `iflag=skip_bytes` will allow the math to be done in bytes as opposed to blocks.

However the options presented by *roaima* (use ddrescue) and *that other guy* (`split -b 10G < /dev/sdd`) are a better way to recover damaged drives, and perform segmented transfers respectively.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are assuming `seek` takes a byte value, when in reality it takes a block count. You should be using `seek=0`, `78125`, `156250`, etc.

However, you can simplify it a lot by getting rid of the `dd`:

```
split -b 10G < /dev/sdd
```

Comment: Elegant. However, the OP writes that the copy attempt "_eventually failed due to a read error_" so it's unlikely that `split` will complete successfully either

Comment: This is good to know about for the next time I need to do this on a drive that actually works. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 3):

> I'm trying to use dd to clone a hard drive I repaired

Don't.

Use [`ddrescue`](https://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/) instead, which copes well with unreadable blocks and other media errors.

Comment: I didn't know about this tool, I'll look it up. Thanks!

Comment: +1; The info page `info ddrescue` is very useful.

Comment: I started using ddrescue a few days ago and it's managed to extract a substantial amount of the data so far. I discovered why my script failed, and marked that as the solution to my initial problem. However ddrescue is best for my overall issue, and I mentioned that in the post.